# Why are the Fourier coefficients of a modular form constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, modular-forms

Let $f$ be a holomorphic modular form (of given weight and level one). Since it $1$-périodic and of moderate growth, it has a Fourier expansion, but this one is a Fourier expansion in $x$, that is
$$f(z) = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} a_n(y) e(nx).$$

I would like to understand why $a_n(y)$ does not depend on $y$. Many sources just state the holomorphicity, but I do not see the relation with this integral? Is that a question of contour integral expression?

Comment: Where did you get this expression for $f(z)$? That is **not** the Fourier expansion of a modular form. The kind of Fourier expansion of a modular form is a power series in $q:=\exp(2\pi i\tau)$. Compare with [modular form](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularForm.html). You probably should have $a_n e^{-2\pi y}$ instead of $a_n(y)$.

Comment: @Somos : If I understand correctly, the question is precisely why there should be such an expansion in terms of powers of $q = e^{2i\pi z}$. Just the periodicity of $f$ insures the existence of a Fourier expansion with regards to $x$ and nothing more. But I believe the existence of a $q$-expansion comes from the additional assumption that $f$ is holomorphic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a presentation that could shed some light on a more general feature about Fourier coefficients of Maass forms, and can be used in a broader setting.

**The case of holomorphic forms.** If $f$ is $1$-periodic, it has a Fourier expansion
$$f(x) = f(x+iy) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n(y) e^{2i\pi n x}.$$

This could be restricted to some $n$ depending on the conditions on $f$ (typically, moderate growth implies $n \geqslant 0$ and cuspidality $n>0$). Holomorphicity means by definition
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) = 0.$$

Inputing it in the Fourier expansion and identifying the coefficients leads to the differential equation $$a_n'(y) + 2\pi n a_n(y) = 0,$$ so that there is a constant $a_n$ such that
$$a_n(y) = a_n e^{-2\pi n y} = a_n e^{2i\pi n (iy)}.$$

We are done. Why is this way interesting? As I announced before, it works in a broader setting.

**The case of Maass forms.** This is another example of the philosophy above. Maass forms $\phi$ are automorphic functions that satisfy a certain invariance (say by $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, so that it is also $1$-periodic) and is an eigenvalue of the weight $k$ Laplacian (see below)

Since it is $1$-periodic, it has a Fourier expansion of the form
$$\phi(x) = \phi(x+iy) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n(y) e^{2i\pi n x}.$$

More precisely, the differential equation satisfied by $\phi$ is
$$\Delta_k \phi = -y^2 \left( \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2} \right) + ik y \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = \nu(1-\nu) \phi.$$

Inputing it in the Fourier expansion and identifying the coefficients leads to the differential equation, we are led to
$$\Delta_k \left( a_n(y) e^{2i\pi n x}\right) = \nu(1-\nu) a_n(y) e^{2i\pi n x}.$$

This is the so-called Whittaker differential equation. It is a second order differential equation, therefore the space of solutions is two-dimensional. But the space of solutions with moderate growth (also part of the definition of a Maass form) is only one dimensional, and is spanned by the Whittaker function $W_{\mathrm{sgn}(n)k}$. We find finally that
$$a_n(y) = a_n W_{\mathrm{sgn}(n)k} (4\pi n y).$$

**The idea.** As soon as $f$ (is $1$-periodic and) satisfies a differential equation, this differential equation translates on the Fourier coefficients $a_n(y)$, that forces $a_n(y)$ to take a certain shape (and automorphic forms, by definition, do satisfy certain partial differential equations).

Answer (score 4):

As you have written it, the coefficients do indeed depend on $y$

$$f(x+iy) = \sum_{n = -m}^{+\infty} a_n(y) \, e^{2i\pi n x}$$

But what remains to be shown is that the coefficients are of the form $a_n(y) = b_n e^{-2\pi n y}$ with $b_n = a_n(0)$ a constant (which will allow us to write $f$ as $f(z) = \sum_{n = -m}^{+\infty} b_n \, e^{2i\pi n z}$). First, recall from Fourier analysis that we have

$$a_n(y) = \int_0^{1} f(t + iy) \, e^{-2 i \pi n t} dt$$

Now comes the complex analysis trick : we can consider $a_n$ as a complex function :

$$a_n(z) = \int_0^{1} f(t + iz) \, e^{-2 i \pi n t} dt$$

And see that $a_n$ is holomorphic because $f$ is. Now, when $z=ix \in i\mathbb{R}$, we can compute

$$a_n(ix) = \int_0^{1} f(t - x) \, e^{-2 i \pi n t} dt \underset{u = t - x}{=}  \int_{-x}^{1-x} f(u) \, e^{-2 i \pi n (u+x)} du = a_n(0) \, e^{-2i \pi n x}$$

Since the holomorphic functions $a_n$ and $z \mapsto a_n(0) e^{-2i \pi n z}$ are equal on $i\mathbb{R}$, they are equal everywhere, and in particular for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$a_n(y) = a_n(0) \, e^{-2i \pi n y}$$

Comment: Great, thank you very much for this very enlightening answer. At the very end, I suppose you mean rather that the function $a_n$ and $a_n(0)e^{-2\pi n \cdot}$ (with no $i$) are equal on $i\mathbb{R}$ and thus on $\mathbb{C}$, and we take it on $y$, and it is fine since $\exp(-2\pi n y) = \exp(2i\pi n (iy))$, adding to the $\exp(2i\pi n x)$ it yields the desired $\exp(2i\pi n z)$. Thanks again for the full proof!